# Gather initial data and act on subsequent child_added

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, firebase

I'm using Firebase to store an array as part of a collection.  When a user visits my webpage, I want to display the entire array's contents.  I can retrieve this via the `value` event.  Users on the page can also add elements to the array.  This should also update the view.

I'm using Knockout.js to maintain the observable array which updates the display.

```
var Model = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    self.times = ko.observableArray();

    self.ref = firebase.child("users/" + id);

    self.ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {

        /* Logic to add each item to `times` goes here
         *
         * there is some logic that only needs to be performed
         * initially on the existing set of elements in the DB
         * such as sorting.  Ideally, this would not be done
         * for the `child_added` callback
         */

        self.ref.off("value");
        self.ref.on("child_added", self.addChild);
    });

    self.addChild = function (snapshot) {
        self.times.push(snapshot.val());
    }
};
```

However, this doesn't work as I expect since it seems like the second `addChild` is called from `child_added` even after `value` is fired.  That is to say `child_added` retrieves all values even though `value` already has.

As an alternative I can use *only* `value` and just `.removeAll` before recreating the array, but this seems very wasteful.

Comment: Why is `self.ref.on("child_added")` nested inside `self.ref.on("value")`?

Comment: @haim770 if I bind to both at the same time, then *both* will fire on the initial data load.  The idea here is to have `child_added` only run *after* the initial data load

Answer (score 1):

This code uses `this` instead of `self` in one instance, which will cause unexpected errors.

Regarding arrays: Using an array to store data is not concurrency safe. When multiple users try to push to the same key, one will be overwritten. Instead, use an object and utilize Firebase's [push](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/push.html) command.

Regarding proper usage of child_added: The documentation for [child_added](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/on.html) states that there is no differentiation between existing and new records:

> Child Added: This event will be triggered once for each initial child
>   at this location, and it will be triggered again every time a new
>   child is added. The DataSnapshot passed into the callback will reflect
>   the data for the relevant child. For ordering purposes, it is passed a
>   second argument which is a string containing the name of the previous
>   sibling child by priority order (or null if it is the first child.)

The point here is to reduce code complexity. We're working in a real-time paradigm; data is in constant flux. There is no need to if/then/else around initial data vs new data vs posted data etc; it doesn't even make a lot of sense for real-time ops.

And finally, answering your question. As you can see from the points above, there is no need to use value in this case:

```
var Model = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    self.times = ko.observableArray();

    self.ref = firebase.child("users/" + id);

    // loads all data at this path, regardless of whether it existed
    // before or after I establish this listener
    self.ref.on("child_added", self.addChild.bind(self));

    self.addChild = function (snapshot) {
        self.times.push(snapshot.val());
    }
};
```

Comment: I had this idea as well, but the main problem is that the data needs to be sorted once it's all retrieved (which can be known by `value` but not by `child_added`).  Sorting in each `child_added` callback would be inefficient.

Comment: You didn't list sorting anywhere in your use case. Please update your question with specifics of the sorting critieria and I'll see if we can find a better solution.

Comment: I updated my question; essentially there is stuff I want to do to the initial set that doesn't need to be done each time an element is added to the set (such as sorting).  I also switched the `this`/`self` usage (I was using it correctly, thanks, but to avoid confusion I just took it out so you may want to remove it from your answer too).  Finally, I am using `.push` for Firebase, so this is treated like an object.  I'm using it as an array for Knockout since the elements become ordinal.